# Make groups of 20 out of set of numbers pseudocode

Tags: python, pseudocode

Suppose I have a set of numbers in a listL

```
qual_list = [6,6,7,8,10,14,13,5,5]
```

I'd like to create groups of 40 or greater (e.g. `[6,14,7,13]` or `[6,8,10,5,13]`) BUT the catch is that I want to create the *most* amount of groups possible. I can only use the number once.

My thought is this:

1. Use the `itertools.combinations` to pick 2 (could have two 20s).
2. Then loop through the `combo_list` to see if the sum of the elements are >=40.
3. Pop the elements out of the `qual_list` that make it through step 2.
4. Then do the same thing but pick 3.
5. Repeat steps picking 4. 5, 6 until the sum of the `qual_list` is <40 and code stops.

It seems like a lot of looping - as well as doesn't ensure that I get the maximum amount of groups, as this method will select the smaller numbers last and most bigger numbers will be grabbed during the selection of smaller picks.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is a variant of *bin packing* which is most probably NP-Complete...

Comment: That is the special words I didn't know to google for. Thanks very much!